# Пытаюсь перенести проект с VS2005 на Qt5

Tags: opengl

В общем собрал заголовочный файл , но так и не понял почему происходит ошибка.

Хотел стандартно с начало заголовочный накинуть . А потом наполнять. Но чёт не вышло

[Вот ссылка на проект](http://3dcpptutorials.sk/index.php?id=31)

Вот код с заголовочного :

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// Version 2.02
//
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <windows.h>

#include "glmath.h"
#include "string.h"

#include <gl/glew.h> // http://glew.sourceforge.net/
#include <gl/wglew.h>

#include <FreeImage.h> // http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma comment(lib, "opengl32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "glu32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "glew32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "FreeImage.lib")

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

extern CString ModuleDirectory, ErrorLog;

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#define BUFFER_SIZE_INCREMENT 1048576

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class CBuffer
{
private:
    BYTE *Buffer;
    int BufferSize, Position;

public:
    CBuffer();
    ~CBuffer();

    void AddData(void *Data, int DataSize);
    void Empty();
    void *GetData();
    int GetDataSize();

private:
    void SetDefaults();
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

extern int gl_max_texture_size, gl_max_texture_max_anisotropy_ext;

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class CTexture
{
protected:
    GLuint Texture;

public:
    CTexture();
    ~CTexture();

    operator GLuint ();

    bool LoadTexture2D(char *FileName);
    bool LoadTextureCubeMap(char **FileNames);
    void Destroy();

protected:
    FIBITMAP *CTexture::GetBitmap(char *FileName, int &Width, int &Height, int &BPP);
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class CShaderProgram
{
protected:
    GLuint VertexShader, FragmentShader, Program;

public:
    GLuint *UniformLocations, *AttribLocations;

public:
    CShaderProgram();
    ~CShaderProgram();

    operator GLuint ();

    bool Load(char *VertexShaderFileName, char *FragmentShaderFileName);
    void Destroy();

protected:
    GLuint LoadShader(char *FileName, GLenum Type);
    void SetDefaults();
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class CCamera
{
protected:
    mat4x4 *ViewMatrix, *ViewMatrixInverse;

public:
    vec3 X, Y, Z, Position;
    float PlanetRadius;

    CCamera();
    ~CCamera();

    void CalculateViewMatrix();
    void Look(vec3 Position, vec3 Reference, float PlanetRadius);
    void OnKeys(SHORT Keys, float FrameTime);
    void OnMouseMove(int dx, int dy);
    void SetViewMatrixPointer(float *ViewMatrix, float *ViewMatrixInverse = NULL);
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class COpenGLRenderer
{
protected:
    int Width, Height;
    mat3x3 NormalMatrix;
    mat4x4 ModelMatrix, ViewMatrix, ProjectionMatrix;

protected:
    CTexture EarthMap, CloudsMap;//, LightsMap;
    CShaderProgram gfs, gfa, sfs, sfa;
    GLuint VerticesVBO, TexCoordsVBO, VerticesCount;
    float InnerRadius, OuterRadius;

public:
    CString Text;

public:
    COpenGLRenderer();
    ~COpenGLRenderer();

    bool Init();
    void Render(float FrameTime);
    void Resize(int Width, int Height);
    void Destroy();
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class COpenGLView
{
protected:
    char *Title;
    int Width, Height, Samples;
    HWND hWnd;
    HGLRC hGLRC;

protected:
    int LastX, LastY;

public:
    COpenGLView();
    ~COpenGLView();

    bool Init(HINSTANCE hInstance, char *Title, int Width, int Height, int Samples);
    void Show(bool Maximized = false);
    void MessageLoop();
    void Destroy();

    void OnKeyDown(UINT Key);
    void OnLButtonDown(int X, int Y);
    void OnMouseMove(int X, int Y);
    void OnMouseWheel(short zDelta);
    void OnPaint();
    void OnRButtonDown(int X, int Y);
    void OnSize(int Width, int Height);
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uiMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR sCmdLine, int iShow);
```

А вот у меня

```
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H

#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

//#include "glmath.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <cstring>

#include "glew.h"
#include "wglew.h"
//#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include "glfw3.h"
#include "glm/glm.hpp"
#include "glm/gtx/transform.hpp"
#include "FreeImage.h"

using namespace std;

class CBuffer
{
private:
    BYTE *Buffer;
    int BufferSize, Position;

public:
    CBuffer();
    ~CBuffer();

    void AddData(void *Data, int DataSize);
    void Empty();
    void *GetData();
    int GetDataSize();

private:
    void SetDefaults();
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

extern int gl_max_texture_size, gl_max_texture_max_anisotropy_ext;

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class CTexture
{
protected:
    GLuint Texture;

public:
    CTexture();
    ~CTexture();

    operator GLuint ();

    bool LoadTexture2D(char *FileName);
    bool LoadTextureCubeMap(char **FileNames);
    void Destroy();

protected:
    FIBITMAP *CTexture::GetBitmap(char *FileName, int &Width, int &Height, int &BPP);
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class CShaderProgram
{
protected:
    GLuint VertexShader, FragmentShader, Program;

public:
    GLuint *UniformLocations, *AttribLocations;

public:
    CShaderProgram();
    ~CShaderProgram();

    operator GLuint ();

    bool Load(char *VertexShaderFileName, char *FragmentShaderFileName);
    void Destroy();

protected:
    GLuint LoadShader(char *FileName, GLenum Type);
    void SetDefaults();
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class CCamera
{
protected:
    glm::mat4x4 *ViewMatrix, *ViewMatrixInverse;

public:
    glm::vec3 X, Y, Z, Position;
    float PlanetRadius;

    CCamera();
    ~CCamera();

    void CalculateViewMatrix();
    void Look(glm::vec3 Position, glm::vec3 Reference, float PlanetRadius);
    void OnKeys(SHORT Keys, float FrameTime);
    void OnMouseMove(int dx, int dy);
    void SetViewMatrixPointer(float *ViewMatrix, float *ViewMatrixInverse = NULL);
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class COpenGLRenderer
{
protected:
    int Width, Height;
    glm::mat3x3 NormalMatrix;
    glm::mat4x4 ModelMatrix, ViewMatrix, ProjectionMatrix;

protected:
    CTexture EarthMap, CloudsMap;//, LightsMap;
    CShaderProgram gfs, gfa, sfs, sfa;
    GLuint VerticesVBO, TexCoordsVBO, VerticesCount;
    float InnerRadius, OuterRadius;

public:
    string Text;

public:
    COpenGLRenderer();
    ~COpenGLRenderer();

    bool Init();
    void Render(float FrameTime);
    void Resize(int Width, int Height);
    void Destroy();
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class COpenGLView
{
protected:
    char *Title;
    int Width, Height, Samples;
    HWND hWnd;
    HGLRC hGLRC;

protected:
    int LastX, LastY;

public:
    COpenGLView();
    ~COpenGLView();

    bool Init(HINSTANCE hInstance, char *Title, int Width, int Height, int Samples);
    void Show(bool Maximized = false);
    void MessageLoop();
    void Destroy();

    void OnKeyDown(UINT Key);
    void OnLButtonDown(int X, int Y);
    void OnMouseMove(int X, int Y);
    void OnMouseWheel(short zDelta);
    void OnPaint();
    void OnRButtonDown(int X, int Y);
    void OnSize(int Width, int Height);
};

#endif // MAIN_H
```

но почему-то выкидывает ошибку хотя сами библиотеки подключил.

```
E:\my_folder\Open_GL\planet_earth_from_space_my\main.h:63: ошибка: extra qualification 'CTexture::' on member 'GetBitmap' [-fpermissive]
     FIBITMAP *CTexture::GetBitmap(char *FileName, int &Width, int &Height, int &BPP);
               ^
```

В общем так и непонял от куда эта ошибка , зашёл в FreeImage.h и увы там ненашёл GetBitmap. может проблемма связанна с тем что FreeImage обновилась ???

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какая ошибка? Поясните, тут нет экстрасенсов.

Comment: @SergMay `E:\my_folder\Open_GL\planet_earth_from_space_my\main.h:63: ошибка: extra qualification 'CTexture::' on member 'GetBitmap' [-fpermissive]
     FIBITMAP *CTexture::GetBitmap(char *FileName, int &Width, int &Height, int &BPP);
               ^`

Comment: дык, это же твой хедер... просто синтаксис неправильный: в определении класса члены объявляются без указания класса/неймспейса... т.е. без `CTexture::`...